# How To Read Data From Dynamically Created TabPageControls

Tags: vb.net, tabpage

I have created some tab pages with an textbox and an button. Whenever I press the button, a new textbox appears under the last one:

```
    Dim txtbox As New TextBox()
    txtbox.Location = New Point(TextBox4.Left, TextBox4.Top + 25 * txtbox7count)
    TabPage7.Controls.Add(txtbox)
    txtbox7count += 1
```

Is there any way to store every textbox input from every tabpage via button_click?

EDIT
Now I tried following:

```
    For Each txtbox As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
        Dim j As String = txtbox.Text
    Next
    Label9.Text = j
```

I experimental tried to read one TextBox-input but my Label9 shows nothing after i pressed the button

Comment: What have you tried? A tabcontrol's tabpages are part of a collection, and so are each tabpage's controls...so you can loop through every control on every tab page with a simple nested for loop

Answer (score -1):

Iterate through all the `TextBox` controls on a Form with the following code:

```
For Each tb As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
    ' Put code here. E.g. tb.Text will return the text of each control within this For..Each statement.

Next
```

**Notes**

- The above code will only work *as is* within the Form class to which it referring to, however `Me` can also be substituted for a reference to any Form in your project.
- Other controls can be iterated through in a similar way by replacing the two occurances of the word `TextBox` with any type of control you desire.